# Need one more IF-statement in Nassi-Shneiderman diagramm

Tags: diagrams, struktex

My LaTeX code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,english]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[pict2e]{struktex} 
\usepackage{babel} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[htb] 
  \centering 
  \begin{struktogramm}(160,92) 
    \descriptionwidth=80pt 
    \assign {Algorithm: description etc.} 
    \assign 
    { 
      \begin{declaration}[Parameters:] 
        \description{\pVar{some paras}} {\pKey{character}-parameter} 
      \end{declaration} 
    } 
    \assign 
    { init:\\ 
      some initialization
    } 

    \ifthenelse[15]{3}{1}{if a something b}{\sTrue}{\sFalse} 

    \case{6}{4}{a\texttt{:=value}}{$a\cdot 1e+03$} 
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} = zero} 
    \switch{$a\cdot 1e+02$} 
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} = one} 
    \switch{$a\cdot 1e+01$} 
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} = two} 
    \switch{$a$} 
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} =three} 
    \caseend 

    \assign[14]{I need here one if statement more !!!!!}

    \change 
    \assign{stop} 
    \ifend 

  \end{struktogramm} 
  \caption{some text} 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

In the left block I need one more IF-statement. How can I manage this problem?

It should look something like that:

[image: goal]

Comment: What should this elusive if statement contain/express?

Comment: @Mico something like that: [link] (https://ibb.co/dqwZ6F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it with

```
\ifthenelse{1}{1}{If condition}{\sTrue}{\sFalse}
\assign{True assignment}
\change
\assign{False assignment}
\endif
```

and remember to increase the overall size of the figure in the `\begin{struktogramm}` so that it does not overlap the caption.

[image: Sample]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,english]{scrbook}

\usepackage[pict2e]{struktex}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{struktogramm}(160,100)
    \descriptionwidth=80pt
    \assign {Algorithm: description etc.}
    \assign
    {
    \begin{declaration}[Parameters:]
      \description{\pVar{some paras}} {\pKey{character}-parameter}
    \end{declaration}
    }
    \assign
    { init:\\
    some initialization
    }

    \ifthenelse[15]{3}{1}{if a something b}{\sTrue}{\sFalse}

    \case{6}{4}{a\texttt{:=value}}{$a\cdot 1e+03$}
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} = zero}
    \switch{$a\cdot 1e+02$}
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} = one}
    \switch{$a\cdot 1e+01$}
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} = two}
    \switch{$a$}
    \assign[17]{\texttt{korpar} =three}

    \caseend

    \ifthenelse[14]{1}{1}{if par 1 \( > \) par 2}{\sTrue}{\sFalse}
    \assign{par 1 * \texttt{korpar}}
    \change
    \assign{par 2 * \texttt{korpar}}
    \ifend

    \change
    \assign{stop}
    \ifend
  \end{struktogramm}
  \caption{some text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```